# Pivoting columns into rows and vice versa

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot into columns and I keep running into errors. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried the below code but I keep getting the red squiggly line under the "FOR" and the first word in the Parenthesis. Here is my code:

```
select d.City,d.Geographic_Region_Name, d.Site_Type
from Site_Profile as d
pivot
(City for Geographic_Region_Name in (City,Geographic_Region_Name,site_type) as pivotable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot is for turning *aggregated rows* into columns.  From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot):

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>   FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>   PIVOT   (
```

The pertinent line:

> `<aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)`

and the rest

```
    FOR    [<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])   ) AS <alias for the pivot table>   
    <optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

You need to use an aggregate function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, `MIN`, etc) before the `FOR`.

Comment: Without knowing more about what your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve, I can't really say which function you should use.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you so very much for the reply, pcdev. Much appreciated